# Add GRUB entries when grub.cfg resides on read-only filesystem

Tags: grub2, readonly

Kali Live USB has grub.cfg on a ISO 9660 partition that is obviously read-only.

I want to add more GRUB entries to pass kernel parameters needed for my laptop to boot correctly, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Kali is anecdotal. This question is about GRUB.

Comment: You can normally edit kernel params from the grub menu - highlight the entry you want to boot and press e to edit the entry.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin Thanks, I already do that now, but I want to make it permanent because on GRUB it behaves as if the Fn key is always on, and when I press the "I" key it writes 5 instead of I.

Comment: Build your own iso: https://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso

Comment: @MichaelDaffin Right, I totally forgot about that option, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDaffin If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it :)